# Passing Event Handler as Parameter to Component in React

Tags: reactjs, events, parameters, components, handler

I have a question about passing a click event to a component. I am getting an error saying that the function that I am passing as a parameter is not a function at evaulation. Here is my code.

```
//Page.js

import { HeaderFrame, BodyFrame, FooterFrame } from './frames/index'

headerClicked = (event) => {
  let extractedText = this.extractContent(event.target.innerHTML);
  console.log(extractedText)
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="Page">
      <label>
        <HeaderFrame headerClicked={(event) => this.headerClicked()}/>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

//HeaderFrame.js

import React from 'react';
import Frame, { FrameContextConsumer } from 'react-frame-component';

const HeaderFrame = (headerClicked) => (
<Frame class='headerBox' head={
   <link type='text/css' href='../css/HeaderBox.css' />
  }>
 <FrameContextConsumer>
  {
    ({document, window}) => {
      debugger; //Uncaught TypeError: headerClicked is not a function
      document.addEventListener("click", headerClicked, false);
      document.designMode = 'On';
      // Render Children
    }
  }
 </FrameContextConsumer>
</Frame>
);

export default HeaderFrame
```

The import/export is working fine, actually at the moment where my debugger is, the console does not know what to make of the headerClicked function...

Answer (score 0):

headerClicked to HeaderFrame is a prop and it doesn't have an event to pass so the way you did isn't right. You need to pass headerClicked like below and you can access the event in the function.

You only need below change to make it work

Change

```
<HeaderFrame headerClicked={(event) => this.headerClicked()}/>
```

To

```
<HeaderFrame headerClicked={this.headerClicked}/>
```